# How to prove a trajectory equation is bounded

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a trajectory equation:

$$0.0908\log{y}-0.0011 y = -0.0988\log{x}+0.001x+c$$

I wanted to prove that this trajectory is bounded because I need to prove the existence of limit cycles in a prey-predator model.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting math formulas.  Also, it would be better if you inform us more about the context, in particular what you have done toward solving the problem.

Comment: Well, first of all we see that $x,z>0$. But then, by playing around with $C$, we see that it's possible to obtain quite large values for $x$ or $y$. Play around with this:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/brmdquz161

Comment: Are there any restrictions for the value of $c$? For example $c>0$?

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pvuqe9kh9g

Comment: No there is no restrictions for $c$

Comment: is there any way to prove them other than plotting the graph?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the equation
$$
A \log{x} - B x + C \log{y} - D y = c
$$
on $\{(x,y) : x > 0, y > 0\}$, where $A, B, C, D > 0$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

The continuous function $x \mapsto A \log{x} - B x$ has limit $-\infty$ as $x \to 0^{+}$ and as $x \to \infty$, hence is bounded from above.  Denote its largest value by $M$.  Similarly, the continuous function $y \mapsto C \log{y} - D y$ has limit $-\infty$ as $y \to 0^{+}$ and as $y \to \infty$, hence is bounded from above.  Denote its largest value by $N$

Further, there is $\xi > 0$ such that 
$$
A \log{x} - B x < c - N \quad \text{ for all } x > \xi,
$$
and there is $\eta > 0$ such that 
$$
C \log{y} - D y < c - M \quad \text{ for all } y > \eta.
$$

For $(x, y)$ with $x > \xi$ we have $A \log{x} - B x + C \log{y} - D y < (c-N) + N = c$.  Similarly, for $(x, y)$ with $y > \eta$ we have $A \log{x} - B x + C \log{y} - D y < M + (c-M)  = c$.

We have proved that the set
$$
\{(x,y) : A \log{x} - B x + C \log{y} - D y = c \}
$$
must be contained in $(0, \xi] \times (0, \eta]$, hence is bounded.